# MVC5 Routing with two parameters in an Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area called News, and within that area I have a Post Controller. The post controller has the following action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string name)
{
...
}
```

I have a route in the NewsAreaRegistration

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "News_post",
        "News/{controller}/{id}/{name}",
        new { action = "Index", controller = "Post",name = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+"}
    );
```

I have also tried without the name object attribute, with and without the id @"\d+ .. Thing is I have this on another site with the exact same setup, just so confused at why it's not working as expected.

Now firstly, the action will resolve:

```
http://example.com/News/Post/Index/3
```

When I want it to resolve to

```
http://example.com/News/Post/3
```

And then I also want this string parameter at the end so it should resolve to

```
http://example.com/News/Post/3/test-post
```

but instead resolves to

```
http://example.com/News/Post/Index/3?test-post
```

I am having a total nightmare with this routing stuff. I have tried to mess around with the Routing attributes but also have no luck there with areas... Any ideas guys?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171240/asp-net-mvc-routing-issue-question-mark-appears-on-my-links

Comment: Hey, the post doesn't have an accepted answer the main post is in need of formatting. I can't even tell what he has changed - if you understand it could you please translate for me pleasE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed part of the issue by making the Route look like this:

> ```
>        context.MapRoute(
>             "News",
>             "News/Post/{id}/{name}",
>             new { action = "Index", controller = "Post" },
>             new { id = @"\d+" }
>         );
> ```

So I removed the UrlParamter.Optional for the name argument. I need to really get my head around how some of these routes work. At times it is so easy, but then others I can't get it to do the simplest things.